# JQuery Mobile Login Page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a sinple jQuery Mobile login page sample. It needs to use MySQL too.
I have googled and found this: [Sample Found](http://devgrow.com/jquery-mobile-php-mvc-framework/) but it's too involved and I need something more simple.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can I ask why has my question been voted down?

Comment: my guess would be you aren't so much asking for help as asking someone to do the work for you. You say you know php so maybe a better question would be "how do i create a jquery mobile page"

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the advice. I'm new here. On my defence I DID specify on the title that I needed a Jquery Mobile Login page. I have now modified my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a legit question.  Probably down voters don't know what the challenge with jQuery Mobile is.  Even the accepted answer below is unrelated to jQuery Mobile.  I want to implement multiple pages web app using a single HTML.  How do I implement ACL?  I have some ideas but I would like to know what other guys have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any credentials-based authentication involving a database will be a bit involved but there are things you can do to make it simple without too great a cost on security. One thing to consider is to make this as simple as possible by removing AJAX from the equation. A simple form that posts back the data rather than trying to AJAX-load the results will simplify your project a bit.

Here's a very simple tutorial on making a login system using PHP and mySQL:  http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

If you can get away with not having a form, you should look into doing a simple .htaccess file with server-side Basic Authentication. No database required for this solution. This would put up a form that asks the person to put in a username an password but wouldn't be styled like your website. If they fail to login, you can kick them to the page of your choice. Otherwise you would show them the website. Here is a link talking about how to set this on the server and generate the needed files: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Comment: I know PHP, I was really looking for something JQuery Mobile specific.

Comment: jQuery mobile is fairly easy to do, check the docs, you add the javascript, and give everything classes see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Comment: If you're familiar with PHP then you have mostly all the tools that you need. Authentication on a mobile site is almost no different than having it accessed from a desktop computer. Depending upon your requirements (you don't list them so I can't be sure what they are) you can use any authentication scheme. It is really just a matter of having a hook for your form to get the results of the authentication request. Sorry that I don't have a specific jQuery Mobile link to give to you but I'm sure you'll be able to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

try this. 
http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Multiple-admin-login-over-MySQL-database-table/64076

as for the jquery mobile part, you'll have to bake that in yourself.

Comment: The link on longer works and I cannot find the tutorial on Tutorialized, which suggests it may have been deleted.